# 502-web server receive an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server, - window server,Java

Tags: java, apache, iis, tomcat7, server

I have create one java webapp and deploy on windows server.
I am using tomcat 7 for that.

My application is running well for many days but don't know why suddenly go slowdown and return 502 Error after redeployment it's work proper again and after some time generate Same issue .

[image] 
I have view so many question related this but not match with my problem.(tomcate7.exe use more than 5gb of RAM)